# Cross domain restriction and limitations from an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Another site uses my iframe domain XYZ.COM. I want to get all html elements of that site (XYZ.COM) and work on it with javascript, just like I do with my own domain page, while using my iframe.

suppose wants to get images of XYZ.COM from iFrame

```
document.parent; // (its ask permission denied) 
document.referrer; // working for me but 
document.referrer.images; //Error: not an object
```

My debug tool is saying permission denied, because of cross domain restriction.
Is there any solution for this, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you use any server side code? PHP? C#? You can easily get images from a page from server code

Comment: server side language php. i can this, but for my app requirements i need do this in my iframe.

Comment: Yes. What you can do instead of iframe the page directly, iframe your page that will get the content from that site say proxy.php?url=http://google.com instead of going to http://google.com directly

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point.

Comment: So say you want to iframe http://google.com, you can create proxy.php that accepts url parameter and get the html content from that url and returns it. Then you use that page to call inside the iframe. Thus you are using one domain and the above js will work.