# Editing Frame items after they have loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I am including a frame in my html document. What I want to do is to change some text in the frame. The frame is not hosted on my website. I have a logic like this:

1. let the frame to load
2. Use jQuery `document.ready` function
3. When the document is completely loaded,I will change the element by `document.getelementbyId("id of element")`

Unfortunately this is not working. I had Googled a lot but didn't find any suitable answer. Can anyone assist me?

Here is the frame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.traffic-zombie.com/en/members/referral?campaignID=1190&backgroundColor=%23ffffff&textColor=%23000000" width="650" height="1000" frameborder="0" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff;"></iframe>
```

Let say I want to change the word **"referral"** in the frame;
here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {      
    
    var c=document.getElementById('zom-status').innerHTML;
    alert(c);
});
    
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do this because of security restrictions. Here is what I found on the net as workarounds: 
http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732054/cross-domain-restriction-and-limitations-from-an-iframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross domain iframe issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not possible. 
[jQuery cross domain iframe scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083112/jquery-cross-domain-iframe-scripting)

You may want to consider grabbing the html for that iframe and then injecting it into the page, at least that way you will have total control. Take a look here to learn about that technique, I believe its far more likely to bear fruit:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/